# How to get the same effect as TweenLite.to in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, tween

I'am using this code:

```
TweenLite.to(auto, 4, {x:666.15, y:375.6});
```

from greensock but I got some issues with it. It woun't go back to his originally x and y coordinates in combination with hittestobject. so does someone have an code or an solution to get the same effect as TweenLite.to??

Comment: You should continue and refine you last question. This question is not about same effect as TweenLite. Greesock tweening platform have no issues with hitTest and other methods.

Comment: Yes, it's called writing 150 lines of your own ActionScript. Not for the faint of heart. Tweener is a viable alternative (https://code.google.com/p/tweener/) but I don't see why it would work, and TweenLite wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TweenLite to tween some object that has hitTest checked on each frame you can use updateTo() or reverse() on Tween. This would look something like this:

```
var tw:TweenLite = TweenLite.to( auto, 4, { x: 555, y: 375, onUpdate: checkHitTest } );
function checkHitTest(){
   //check here for possible hit and call updateTo method
   tw.updateTo({ x: 20, y: 30 }, false );
   //last parameter defines if tween should be modified or if new tween should be created
}
```